# How to Allow Remote Access to PostgreSQL database

Tags: windows, postgresql, virtual-machine

I have PostgreSQL 9.2 Installed in Windows 7 and I have windows XP installed in Virtual Machine, how do I connect these two databases and allow remote access to add/edit the database from both Systems ?

Comment: Note that all answers enable access to *all* PostgreSQL databases on the server (in your case running on Win 7). Makes sense for exposing the server to a VM like here. In a more general case of course, one would restrict remote access to specific databases and users for security reasons.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

In order to remotely access a PostgreSQL database, you must set the two main PostgreSQL configuration files:

postgresql.conf
pg_hba.conf

Here is a brief description about how you can set them (note that the following description is purely indicative: To configure a machine safely, you must be familiar with all the parameters and their meanings)

First of all configure PostgreSQL service to listen on port 5432 on all network interfaces in Windows 7 machine:
open the file `postgresql.conf` (usually located in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\data) and sets the parameter

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Check the network address of WindowsXP virtual machine, and sets parameters in pg_hba.conf file (located in the same directory of postgresql.conf) so that postgresql can accept connections from virtual machine hosts.
For example, if the machine with Windows XP have 192.168.56.2 IP address, add in the `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
host all all 192.168.56.1/24 md5
```

this way, PostgreSQL will accept connections from all hosts on the network 192.168.1.XXX.

Restart the PostgreSQL service in Windows 7 (Services-> PosgreSQL 9.2: right click and restart sevice). Install pgAdmin on windows XP machine and try to connect to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot, unfortunately it didn't work, all the changes I did were in the windows 7 side and when I restarted the PostgreSQL service it wouldn't start again until I remove the Virtual Machine IP address from pg_hba.conf, should I add anything in the virtual machines files ?

Comment: Have you checked Windows 7 firewall? Can you ping Windows7 from WindowsXP? You can also try with `netstat -a -n` command to check if postgresql is listening on the addresses

Comment: Nvm dude, it worked, it was an IP address problem, now it's working like a charm :)

Comment: django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "multibot_crm"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "multibot_crm"

Comment: If your local IP changes, you'll have to reconfigure. Is there an option to include all "sub-ips"? For example, "192.168.*.*/0" ?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka you can use the slash notation to indicate the subnet. If you need to include all addresses starting with 192.168.*.* you can specify 192.168.0.0/16 in the pg_hba.conf configuration file.

Comment: follow this and it's working for me
https://tecadmin.net/postgresql-allow-remote-connections/

Answer (score 91):

After set `listen_addresses = '*'` in **postgresql.conf**

Edit the **pg_hba.conf** file
and add the following entry at the very end of file:

```
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5
host    all             all              ::/0                            md5
```

For **finding the config files** [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47790659/postgres-find-configuration-files-in-linux/47790660#47790660) might help you.

Comment: yes it works. finally i could access postgresql using pgadmin from my local network. thank you.

Comment: django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "multibot_crm"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "multibot_crm"

Comment: conf file location: `psql -U postgres -c 'SHOW config_file'`. Default in Ubuntu: `/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf`. Also, service should be restarted: `sudo service postgresql restart` - on ubuntu.

Comment: dont forget `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`

Comment: Mine worked. But I had to use "trust" instead of "md5". Also, the second line is needed only for ipv6 connections.

Comment: the same here, i had to use 'trust' instead of 'md5'

Comment: Do _not_ use **trust** in combination with **all all 0.0.0.0/0** - that makes your server practically open to everyone. As mentioned [in PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/auth-methods.html#AUTH-TRUST): "This method should only be used when there is adequate operating-system-level protection on connections to the server."

Comment: Important: Sometimes, the line listen_addresses = '*' IS COMMENTED. Please remove the #, otherwise it will not work

Comment: This works for me in v13 without changing `postgresql.conf` at all - there is no `listen_addresses` in the file for me anyway

Comment: One more tip: `listen_addresses` shouldd be `'*'` instead of `"*"`.

Answer (score 41):

In addition to above answers suggesting (1) the modification of the configuration files pg_hba.conf and (2) postgresql.conf and (3) restarting the PostgreSQL service, **some Windows computers might also require incoming TCP traffic to be allowed on the port** (usually `5432`).

To do this, you would need to open Windows Firewall and add an inbound rule for the port (e.g. 5432).

Head to *Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall > Advanced Settings > Actions (right tab) > Inbound Rules > New Rule… > Port > Specific local ports* and type in the port your using, usually 5432 *>* (defaults settings for the rest and type any name you'd like)

[image: Windows firewall settings]

Now, try connecting again from pgAdmin on the client computer. Restarting the service is not required.

Comment: This worked for a Windows 7 guest OS running on a Windows 10 host on VirtualBox.

Comment: That's it ! and don't forget to make a Routing rule into your router !

Answer (score 21):

If using PostgreSql 9.5.1, please follow the below configuration:

1. Open hg_hba.conf in pgAdmin
   [image: pgAdmin]
2. Select your path, and open it, then add a setting
   [image: pg_hba.conf]
3. Restart postgresql service

In order to allow `192.X.X.X` use `192.0.0.0/8`.

In order to allow `192.168.X.X` use `192.168.0.0/16`.

In order to allow `192.168.1.X` use `192.168.1.0/24`.

In order to allow only `192.168.1.2` use `192.168.1.2/32`

Comment: so your network ip address is 0.0.0.0/0 ? or is that just accept all ip address?

Comment: @ziggy : All IP addresses. In order to allow X.X.X.X use 0.0.0.0/0. In order to allow 192.X.X.X use 192.0.0.0/8. In order to allow 192.168.X.X use 192.168.0.0/8. In order to allow 192.168.1.X use 192.0.0.0/16. In order to allow 192.168.1.X use 192.168.1.0/24. In order to allow only 192.168.1.2 use 192.168.1.2/32

Comment: Respect, this helped

Answer (score 2):

This is a complementary answer for the specific case of using AWS cloud computing (either EC2 or RDS machines).

Besides doing everything proposed above, when using AWS cloud computing you will need to set your inbound rules in a way that let you access to the ports.

Please check [this answer about 'inbound rules'](https://serverfault.com/a/880710/580493).

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this to your pg_hba.conf and restart your PostgreSQL.

> host    all             all             192.168.56.1/24            md5

This works with VirtualBox and host-only adapter enabled. If you don't use Virtualbox you have to replace the IP address.

Comment: Thanks but I'm using Microsoft Virtual PC, how do I know which IP address to add ?

Answer (score -4):

For PostgreSQL 13, I could not use scram-sha-256 encryption for remote connections for some reason.  This worked.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256 # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256 # IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256 # IPv6 local connections
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256 # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust # <---------- remote connections
```

Comment: Please DO NOT do this, this leaves your database access open to all without password

Comment: do not do `host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust # `
instead
`host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               scram-sha-256 # `
is better