# Connect to a PostgreSQL database in a Server from a local machine R

Tags: r, postgresql, ip, host, rpostgresql

When you connect to PostgreSQL thorough RPostgreSQL for example I do the following.

```
m <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(m, host = "localhost", user= "postgres", password="admin", 
dbname = "postgres")
```

But if you want to connect to a postgreSQL in a Server, I'm not sure how to do it. I'd do the following:

```
m <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(m, host = "10.100.100.10", port = "5432", user= "postgres", 
                 password="admin", dbname = "postgres")
```

and this gives me this error:

**Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect postgres@10.100.100.10 on dbname "postgres"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You (or whoever admins the server) needs to allow access from another machine over tcp/ip -- this is turned off by default. See for example

- [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580066/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-postgresql-database)
- [this blog post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html)
- [this PostgreSQL documentation entry](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Comment: thanks , though I think the access is open because I have postgreSQL in my local machine and I can connect to the database in the server using pgAdmin. The problem is in R where it only listen the host as a localhost.