# Can't connect remotely to PSQL database?

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, connection

I have a problem with connection to my PSQL database. I made a program in C# and when I published it and placed it on another PC (set that it gets data from db on PC that I programmed application), it worked perfectly. Now I wanted to transfer that db to another PC that will run 24/7, and I had a struggle doing that, but I made it (manually in the end). Now when db is set on that 24/7 PC, I can't connect to it. 
For ex. When I start my program from laptop that I used for programming, I get this:

[image]

My connection string looks like this:

```
string Connectionstring = "Server=192.168.130.240;Port=5433;User Id=postgres;" +
"Password=password;Database=postgres;";
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Connectionstring);
conn.Open();
```

P.S. One difference that I noticed is that on my laptop that I used to program my connection string was the same only with IP: 127.0.0.1, and whenever I open PSQL it automatically starts and its already logged in, but on this 24/7 PC when I start psql.exe it starts and then shuts down, but when I start SQL Shell(PSQL) I need to put in server,database,port,username and password every time I start it.

If someone has any idea how to fix this, please help because this is last step of my project and I can't get it to work...

Comment: Assuming the machines are on the same network & can see each other - the port is usually 5432, so try that. If no luck ensure there is a rule in the firewall on the machine running the server to allow incoming connections on the port.

Comment: @AlexK. I switched port when I was programming to 5433 coz something was wrong, but I'll try both solutions and get back to you

Comment: One possible issue is that you need to configure postgresql to accept non-local connections. You do this by adding your address to pg_hba.conf. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: In order to remotely access a PostgreSQL database, you must set the two main PostgreSQL configuration files:
postgresql.conf
pg_hba.conf 
check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580066/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-postgresql-database

Comment: Also check if firewall exception for incoming request is enabled for port 5432, or which ever port you have configured for database.

Comment: @AshishKamat That firewall setting solved the problem, thank you =), post it as an answer so I can vote it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add firewall Exception for incoming TCP connection of PgSQL Database port.
By default, it is 5432 port.
This is required for cases, where database is kept on remote machines.