# How can I run POSTGRESQL server on a public IP

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have installed PostgreSQL 11 on my Amazon Lightsail windows virtual machine. It is running on " http://127.0.0.1:59791/browser/" properly.But I want to run it on a public IP. How can I do it?
Please help me.

Comment: see this instruction, paragraph **e** : `https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-connect-postgresql-db/?nc1=h_ls`

Comment: Postgres doesn't use http so it can't "work properly" with a http link.

Comment: i am not using POSTGRESQL of amazon lightsail. I have download it from internet and installed. that POSTGRESQL server i want to run on instance public IP. Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try using standard way of making PostgreSQL listen on public IP addresses? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580066/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-postgresql-database Also, Amazon Lightsail offers managed PostgreSQL 11.

Comment: Your server have not public IP?

Comment: I am using virtual machine. Within that machine I have downloaded postgres software then installed.