# Setting up a Remotely Accessible Postgres Database with Linux and PGAdmin

Tags: linux, postgresql, networking, pgadmin

I'm trying to set up a **remotely accessible Postgres database**. I want to host this databse on one **Linux** based device (HOST), and to access it on another Linux based device (CLIENT).

In my specific case, HOST is a desktop device running Ubuntu. CLIENT is a Chromebook with a Linux virtual system. (I know. But it's the closest thing to a Linux based device that I have to hand.

### Steps Already Taken to Set Up the Database

1. Installed the required software on HOST using APT.

```bash
PGP_KEY_URL="https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc"
POSTGRES_URL_STEM="http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/"
POSTGRES_URL="$POSTGRES_URL_STEM `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main"
POSTGRES_VERSION="12"
PGADMIN_URL_SHORT="https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub"
PGADMIN_URL_STEM="https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt"
PGADMIN_TO_ECHO="deb $PGADMIN_URL_STEM/`lsb_release -cs` pgadmin4 main"
PGADMIN_PATH="/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list"

sudo apt install curl --yes
sudo apt install gnupg2 --yes
wget --quiet -O - $PGP_KEY_URL | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb $POSTGRES_URL" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
sudo apt install postgresql-$POSTGRES_VERSION --yes
sudo apt install postgresql-client-$POSTGRES_VERSION --yes

sudo curl $PGADMIN_URL_SHORT | sudo apt-key add
sudo sh -c "echo \"$PGADMIN_TO_ECHO\" > $PGADMIN_PATH && apt update"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pgadmin4 --yes
```

2. Create a new Postgres user.

```bash
NU_USERNAME="my_user"
NU_PASSWORD="guest"
NU_QUERY="CREATE USER $NU_USERNAME WITH superuser password '$NU_PASSWORD';"

sudo -u postgres psql -c "$NU_QUERY"
```

3. Created the new server and database. I did this manually, using the PGAdmin GUI.
4. Added test data, a table with a couple of records. I did this with a script.
5. Followed the steps given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580066/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-postgresql-database) to make the databse remotely accessible.

### Steps Already Taken to Connect to the Database REMOTELY

1. Installed PGAdmin on CLIENT.
2. Attempted to connect using PGAdmin. I used the "New Server" wizard, and entered:

> Host IP Address: 192.168.1.255 
> Port: 5432 (same as when I set up the database on HOST) 
> User: my_user 
> Password: guest

However, when I try to save the connection, PGAdmin responds after a few seconds saying that the connection has **timed out**.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure `listen_addresses` in `/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf` like this:

`listen_addresses = '*'`

Next make sure your firewall doesn't block the connection by checking if telnet can connect to your server:

```
$ telnet 192.168.1.255 5432
Connected to 192.168.1.255.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If you see `Connected` network connectivity is ok. Next you have to configure access rights for remote hosts.

Comment: Thank you for alerting me to the `telnet` trick. I can get a connection at 192.168.1.159 5432 - that must be the address I want. However, when I try to connect in PGAdmin, I get a message beginning: 'No pg_hba.conf entry for host 192.168.1.208...' But I have already amended my pg_hba.conf, on both HOST and CLIENT, to include the line: `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`!

Comment: Your error was "timed out". Authentication is the next part of your quest but I believe it's out of this question. 
did you see this manual https://www.netiq.com/documentation/cloud-manager-2-5/ncm-install/data/bf9b2zv.html?

Comment: Thanks again for helping me with this. I actually decided that this question was inappropriate Stack Overflow, so I asked [a new question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1105921/why-does-postgres-tell-me-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host-when-i-have-already) instead. This new question includes an updated summary of the current situation.