How to keep datas remain after switch to deocker for deployment(Wagtail into an existing Django project)
let me clear what is going on.......
am working on wagtail project which is comes from ff this steps:
-How to add Wagtail into an existing Django project(https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/add_to_django_project.html)
and am try to switch project to docker for deployment and do not forget am "import sql dump into postgres", and am aim to run on uwsgi and everything is perfect no error;but there are problem after everything i can't see anything on pages and when i try to access admin there is no any existed pages(which means i should create pages from scratch)
here are some of cmds i used:
-docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml build
-docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml up
-docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py createsuperuser"
if it needed here is the Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.9-slim-bookworm
LABEL maintainer="londonappdeveloper.com"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev \
    gcc \
    exiftool \
    imagemagick \
    libmagickwand-dev \
    libmagic1 \
    redis-tools \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Set up virtual environment
RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip

# Copy application files
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
COPY . /app
COPY ./scripts /scripts

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

# Install Python dependencies
RUN /py/bin/pip install -r /requirements.txt

# Set up directories for static and media files
RUN adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home app && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/static && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/media && \
    chown -R app:app /vol && \
    chmod -R 755 /vol && \
    chmod -R +x /scripts


ENV PATH="/scripts:/py/bin:$PATH"

USER app

CMD ["run.sh"]


docker-compose-deploy.yml:
version: '3.9'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/web
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASS=${DB_PASS}
      - SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=${ALLOWED_HOSTS}
      - REDIS_URL=${REDIS_URL}
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    links:
      - db:db
      - redis:redis
  
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
  
  proxy:
    build:
      context: ./proxy
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - 80:8000
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/static
  
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
  
volumes:
  postgres-data:
  static-data:

i try to see the project working as b4 apply docker but now it is empty nothing showing and also in admin page there is no any pages it is empty.

2 options: the import didn't work OR your app container isn't connecting to the db/user used in the import. I would exec into the db container and check it has the user(s), databases, and data you expect. Then I would exec into the app container and try connecting from the psql command line with the db + user you verified in the db container. I expect you will find the disconnect in one of those steps.

Thanks for your quick reply ,but i checked twice and the import did work i checked the content like tables,etc and it is fine there is no any erros.

Then I am betting you are not connecting as the same user OR the PG user you are connecting as doesn't have access from your app container. If you see data when connecting via psql in the db container, can you use the same command in the app container? If not, try items like this SO post to fix your db config https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580066/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-postgresql-database

I thought the problem was related to importing .sql into docker postgres database because even if it seems worked it showed me there are conflict because i try to import after migrate, so i need help related to the way import dump b4 running migrate.The order really matter.

Answering based on yesterday's comment about import conflicts when importing into a database with existing migrations:
Option 1: connect to the postgres database, drop your $DB_NAME database, recreate it, then import without running the migrations first. Reference
Option 2: Configure your PG container to import your data dump on initialization. To do this one, you will first have to destroy the data volume you have for PG since this only happens the first time the database is started. For details see the "Initialization scripts" section of the official image docs.

you are my brother cuz you couldn't keep silent when i was in trouble Thanks cnk.
and for others pls also refer this one to import data to postgres container:How to import restore database dump.

but i have media folder and i wanna include in project, how i should handle it???

You can use a volume for the media folder like you do for the static-data or you can use remote storage like S3 or R2

big bro Thanks for your support and i know i have some online friends who's name is cnk.
